# Formatting a date time string

Tags: kotlin, threetenbp

I have the following date which we get from an API `2022-11-23 06:12:31`

I am wondering if my approach is the best.

And I need to display in this format `23 November 2022`

I am using `substringbefore` to remove the time portion so I am left with the following: `"2022-11-23"`

I am using `org.threeten.bp`

```
val DAY_MONTH_YEAR_DISPLAY_FORMATTER =
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM yyyy").withZone(ZoneOffset.systemDefault())

fun formatAsFullMonthDisplayDate(localDateTime: String): String {
    return try {
        LocalDate.parse(localDateTime.substringBefore(" "), DAY_MONTH_YEAR_DISPLAY_FORMATTER).buildDate()
    } catch (ignored: Exception) {
        ""
    }
}

private fun LocalDate.buildDate(): String {
    return buildString {
        append(this@buildDate.dayOfMonth)
        append(" ")
        append(this@buildDate.month)
        append(" ")
        append(this@buildDate.year)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question here? You have mentioned what you have done but not what your actual question is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this:

```
val inputDate = "2022-11-23 06:12:31"
val outputFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"
val inputFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
val outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(outputFormat)

val date = LocalDateTime.parse(inputDate, inputFormat)
val formattedDate = date.format(outputFormatter)

println(formattedDate) // "23 November 2022"
```